# Gridview Datakeys problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the LocationID for the row in the gridview. grdFavoriteMerchant is the gridID. I am new to using gridview.

I am using this part of code to get LocationID but it gets MerchantID when row.RowIndex = 0.

```
int LocationID = Convert.ToInt32(grdFavoriteMerchant.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
```

In the aspx, i have `DataKeyNames="Merchant_id, zipcode, Location_id"`

I am wondering how i can give hardcoded "LocationID" in the above code to get LocationID back.

I hope i am clear :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int LocationID = (int)grdFavoriteMerchant.DataKeys[row.RowIndex][2];
```